# Properties of Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

The book I am using is *Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems* by Lawrence Parko.

Seeking to confirm my attempt at proving the following.

> Use the lemma in this section to show that if $T$ is an invertible linear transformation then $$||T^{-1}||\geq \frac{1}{||T||}$$

The lemma the question is referring to is as follows:

For $S,T\in L(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}$,

- 1) $||T(\vec{x})||\leq ||T||\cdot ||\vec{x}||$
- 2) $||TS||\leq||T||||S||$
- 3) $||T^k|| \leq ||T||^k$ for $k = 1, 2, \dots$

Using this I have the following:

> > Let $T$ be a invertible linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $TT^{-1}=T^{-1}T=I$. Then by the lemma, $||I||= ||TT^{-1}||\leq ||T||\cdot||T^{-1}||$. Since $1 \leq \sqrt{n} = ||I||$, then we have 
> >     \begin{array}
> > & 1 & \leq & ||T||\cdot||T^{-1}|| & \Leftrightarrow & \frac{1}{||T||}\leq ||T^{-1}||
> > \end{array}.

Is my argument valid?

---

Thank You for your time. I appreciate any feedback. May you have a wonderful day.

Comment: Your argument seems valid to me. Let me point out that it is not clear in all your question what norm on linear operators you are using. Is it the sqrt of the squares of the entries (for which $||I||=\sqrt{n}$), or the operator norm (for which $||I||=1$)?